# <ul> list only showing contents of first <li>, ignoring second <li>

Tags: html, css, lightbox

Ryan Seddon of the CSSNinja (@ryanseddon on Twitter and GitHub) wrote a great CSS-only lightbox gallery that even allows for images with text boxes (`<span>`s) and doesn't rely on the :target selector. It uses `<ul>`s and the :checked checkbox selector to fix a lot of common problems that the :target selector-method invokes.

I've attempted to implement his code and made a sandbox version of it for my needs before injecting it into my website. Everything seems to work well enough except when I click on the second `<li>`/image, instead of bringing up the contents from that portion of code, it just regurgitates the information from the first `<li>`/image.

Where am I going wrong? I want to have several of these images that click-and-turn-into lightboxed image+text boxes, lined up like a typical image gallery on a webpage. Bonus points if you can help me make it so that clicking *inside* the text box *does not* make the lightbox go away, and only clicking anywhere *outside* the text box makes it go away.

Here is my working JSfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hideto/q7ghLvkd/

How to get it to read the info from the exact `<li>`/image clicked on and not just copy/bring up the first `<li>`/image's info?

Comment: You have two IDs the same, don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I had no idea this kind of stuff was possible. Awesome.

I just tweaked your fiddle to change the id of the second radio to 'bio2' and the accompanying label to reference for="bio2" - that seems to have fixed it.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7ghLvkd/2/

```
        <label class="animated pulse1" for="bio2"><img src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/testpage/biogallery/gr_ninja-attack_med.gif" width="100" height="102" alt="The CSS Ninja" title="Kieran" /></label>
        <input type="radio" id="bio2" name="Staff" />
```

So the problem was that you had two elements with the same id, and generally in HTML an element's id should be unique within the entire page.

I don't know about your bonus points challenge - I am still looking at it to work out how a click opens it! - but did you know in SO you can offer a bounty if you aren't getting the responses you want? ie, you genuinely can offer bonus points!

Comment: Thanks for your help! That was the problem!

Ryan Seddon deserves all the credit, however. Here's the link to his site where he explains/teaches you how to do clickable lightboxes using `<ul>`s and `<li>`s.

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/futurebox3

Comment: There's one other problem. The ID code seems to have some CSS styling it in the CSS pane. Is there a way so I don't have to repeat the CSS for this with #bio2, #bio3, #bio4, etc? Does the ID need to have the style code on it? Can we apply that same code in a better, more ID-independent way? It's early in the morning for me so I'm not sure how to achieve that, evne if it's obvious.

Comment: I think you could use the 'attribute begins with' selector to do that... input[id^='bio'] should match <input id="bio1" /> and <input id="bio2" />